# Avoid tautological-compare warning in template

Tags: c++, templates

I have a template class that should return different values if the (unsigned) parameter is even or odd, like in this test case:

```
template <unsigned X> class t {
public:
    static int get(int *n) {
        if constexpr (1 == (X & 1))
            return n[X] + n[X-1] + t<X-2>::get(n);
        else
            return n[X] + t<X-1>::get(n);
    }
};

template <> class t<1> {
public:
    static int get(int *n) {
        return n[0] + n[1];
    }
};

template <> class t<0> {
public:
    static int get(int *n) {
        return n[0];
    }
};

int main() {
    int x[9] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    return t<8>::get(x);
}
```

This is part of a large code that uses vector instructions, so it processes more than one element at a time if possible.

Problem is, newer GCC versions emit the following warning:

```
temp.cc: In instantiation of ‘static int t<X>::get(int*) [with unsigned int X = 8]’:
temp.cc:27:18:   required from here
temp.cc:4:25: warning: bitwise comparison always evaluates to false [-Wtautological-compare]
    4 |         if constexpr (1 == (X & 1))
      |                       ~~^~~~~~~~~~
```

The warning is given regardless of adding the "constexpr" word.

IMHO, GCC should not emit that warning here, as the code is not always false - only in the specific template specialization.

Is there a way to avoid this warning without resorting to writing template specializations depending on another parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to avoid this warning without resorting to writing template specializations depending on another parameter?

In the latest version, [gcc does not warn about this](https://godbolt.org/z/G4Mrfn) so adding an exception seems reasonable:

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wtautological-compare"
if constexpr (1 == (X & 1))
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

Comment: Well, after testing various GCC versions, it is a reported bug: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=96742

Just the fix was not back-ported to the gcc-10 branch.

Comment: @dmsc Exactly - so, in order to make your `constexpr` _not_ report warnings (where it shouldn't) in old compiler versions, just mute them. Motivate it with a comment that the vendor has fixed the problem in later versions.